# How to use BigInt exponentiation with Babel?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Consider this:

```
const a = BigInt(2);
const b = BigInt(2);
const c = a ** b;
```

Babel will convert this to:

```
var a = BigInt(2);
var b = BigInt(2);
var c = Math.pow(a, b);
```

However, `Math.pow` doesn't work with `BigInt`. As far as I know, it's impossible to get Babel to ignore a certain line. I found `babel-plugin-transform-bigint`, but I don't want to load a polyfill for this. If `BigInt` isn't supported, then I'll just set an upper limit for the input.

My options are to override `Math.pow` or manually implement exponentiation. Is it impossible to use the native `**` operator with `BigInt` and Babel at the moment?

Also, just confirming, `**` would be a syntax error if it isn't supported right?

Edit: babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
      useBuiltIns: 'usage',
      corejs: '2',
      exclude: [
        'babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator',
        'babel-plugin-transform-regenerator',
      ],
    }],
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    ['@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx', { pragma: 'h' }],
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
    /*
    Async/await increases file size by a lot.
    ['module:fast-async', {
      'compiler': { 'promises': true, 'generators': false, 'useRuntimeModule': true },
    }],
    ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs', {
      'strictMode': false,
    }],
    */
  ],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: ['transform-react-remove-prop-types'],
    },
  },
  sourceType: 'unambiguous',
};
```

Comment: Care to share your `.babelrc`?

Comment: To be able to use `**` on native BigInts, I think you'd either need something like `new Function` or `eval` to handle the dynamic syntax (otherwise a syntax error will be thrown). Maybe consider using a BigInt-like library instead?

Comment: `eval` is interesting, that might be the only way.
@georg added the Babel config.

Comment: thanks. If you want ** to be left as is, add `babel-plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator` to the exclude section.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you getting this problem in **Create React App**. See the following thread and solutions:

https://github.com/0xs34n/starknet.js/issues/37#issuecomment-955797303
and
https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/13109#issuecomment-826287089

Basically you can change the `browserlist` of your `package.json` in order to prevent babel from running its `transform-exponentiation-operator` plugin like so:

```json
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      "chrome >= 67",
      "edge >= 79",
      "firefox >= 68",
      "opera >= 54",
      "safari >= 14"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
```

---

For non-browser react environments such as `react-native-macos`, `react-native-windows`, `electron`, see the gist here for a way to create your own `babel.config.js` to choose which plugins/transforms to run:

https://gist.github.com/karanjthakkar/3241808022a75d8068f35a33b57e90c5

There's a twitter thread explaining the problem:
https://twitter.com/geekykaran/status/1082218546799755266

An example of `babel.config.js` without the `babel-plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator` applied:

```js
const lazyImports = require('metro-react-native-babel-preset/src/configs/lazy-imports');

module.exports = (api) => {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    comments: false,
    compact: true,
    plugins: [
      '@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types',
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding',
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT: '@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping',
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', {
        loose: true,
      }],
      '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
      '@babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from',
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT: '@babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties',
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT: '@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring',
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT: '@babel/plugin-transform-function-name',
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT: '@babel/plugin-transform-literals',
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT: '@babel/plugin-transform-parameters',
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT: '@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx',
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT: '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex',
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from',
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
        {
          strict: false,
          strictMode: false, // prevent "use strict" injections
          lazy: importSpecifier => lazyImports.has(importSpecifier),
          allowTopLevelThis: true, // dont rewrite global `this` -> `undefined`
        },
      ],
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT: '@babel/plugin-transform-classes',
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT: '@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions'
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT: '@babel/plugin-transform-spread',
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT: [
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT:   '@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals',
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT:   {loose: true}, // dont 'a'.concat('b'), just use 'a'+'b'
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT: ],
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT: '@babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator',
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT: '@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign',
      // SUPPORTED BY DEFAULT: ['@babel/plugin-transform-for-of', {loose: true}],
      // 'metro-react-native-babel-preset/src/transforms/transform-symbol-member',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name',
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
      ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', {
        helpers: true,
        regenerator: true,
      }],
    ],
  };
};
```

Remember to reset the cache when restarting the bundler with npm/yarn

```sh
npm start -- --reset-cache
```